# Generate Preact App to a single bundle js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, build, preact

This is could be a newbie question. I have created a preact app which uses assets images that are locally stored in the preact app folder.

Using the preacts-cli build command I get several css map and a js files.

I would like to generate an single bundle file that i could place onto any website within the header with needed prereacts cdn's and it will successfully work.

Would greatly appreciate some direction to go towards as i am clueless as of now

Comment: Are you talking about base64 encoding the images and strinifying the CSS into JS? I assume you're using Preact-CLI, but that's the wrong tool for the job in all reality. Try [Microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle)

Comment: @rschristian Hi :) I've wanted to make it so that my preact app could be added to any website with ease, currently the files are built into several files but I wanted to have another build script which would build it into a single js file and then i could use preact cdns to make it work fully

Comment: I get that, but Preact-CLI is for making progressive web apps. What you're wanting is more of a widget, and Preact-CLI is not at all suited for that task. There's a fair few issues open on the Preact-CLI repo with people providing hacky workarounds to get it done but they're not great. It's just not behavior we support with that tool. You're going to have to do a lot of configuration edits to make it work along the lines of what you're looking for. Microbundle is better here.

Comment: Will i be able to add Microbundle on top of what i have done with Preact-CLI?

Comment: Depends on what you're referring to. Source code? Sure. Bundler config? No.

Comment: @rschristian Hi once again! i've added the following command 
**microbundle -i src/index.js -o dist/bundle.js --define process.env.NODE_ENV=production --css inline --no-pkg-main -f umd**
When i include the bundle in a basic html page I get an error of **FactoryWithThrowingShims.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'div')** tried multiple things and it still seems not to work :(

Comment: I have no way to debug without a reproduction.

Comment: @rschristian I get the error thats assuming linked to styled components: 
**D = o.default.div(B || (B = a(["\n  display: grid;\n** <= error **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'div')Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'div')**

Comment: This is better suited for a bug tracker. That's an error message, not a reproduction that I can do anything to help with.